# How to pass function objects to web workers in html?

Tags: javascript, html, svg, web-worker

I am animating an svg element in my html code. Basically I have an interval, and each time it runs, it transforms several svg tags. And this causes much lag in the web app. Is there a way I can create a web worker and in there transform the object?

```
    var walk = function() {
        var step = 0, rotation_angle = 50, head_angle = 10, torso_angle = 5, arm_angle = 15;
        interval = setInterval(function() {
            main.transform(-(Math.sin(step * 0.8)) * head_angle, 1, 1, w/2, h/2, 0, 0);
            head.transform(-(Math.cos(step * 0.8)) * torso_angle, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
            torso.transform(-(Math.cos(step * 0.8)) * torso_angle, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
            leftArm.transform((Math.sin(step * 0.8)) * arm_angle, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
            rightArm.transform(-(Math.cos(step * 0.8)) * arm_angle, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
            rightLeg.transform(-(Math.cos(step)) * rotation_angle, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
            leftLeg.transform((Math.sin(step)) * rotation_angle, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
            step += 0.1;
        }, 0.5);                             
    };
```

For example, I want to make a walking animation, so I rotate these things. `main`, `head`, ... are function objects that I created that has the transform function property. But is there a way I can change it to something like

```
    var walk = function() {
        var step = 0, rotation_angle = 50, head_angle = 10, torso_angle = 5, arm_angle = 15;
        interval = setInterval(function() {
            new web_worker(function() {
                 main.transform(-(Math.sin(step * 0.8)) * head_angle, 1, 1, w/2, h/2, 0, 0);
            });
            new web_worker(function() {
                 head.transform(-(Math.sin(step * 0.8)) * head_angle, 1, 1, w/2, h/2, 0, 0);
            });
            new web_worker(function() {
                 torso.transform(-(Math.sin(step * 0.8)) * head_angle, 1, 1, w/2, h/2, 0, 0);
            });
            new web_worker(function() {
                 leftArm.transform(-(Math.sin(step * 0.8)) * head_angle, 1, 1, w/2, h/2, 0, 0);
            });
            new web_worker(function() {
                 rightArm.transform(-(Math.sin(step * 0.8)) * head_angle, 1, 1, w/2, h/2, 0, 0);
            });
            new web_worker(function() {
                 rightLeg.transform(-(Math.sin(step * 0.8)) * head_angle, 1, 1, w/2, h/2, 0, 0);
            });
            new web_worker(function() {
                 leftLeg.transform(-(Math.sin(step * 0.8)) * head_angle, 1, 1, w/2, h/2, 0, 0);
            });
            step += 0.1;
        }, 0.5);                             
    };
```

So that all the transforms happen concurrently in each interval function?

Thanks

Comment: webWorkers cannot access DOM objects in your page in any way.

Comment: So they can't be used to do something like this?

Comment: What about these examples

http://sourceforge.net/p/jsclipper/wiki/Web%20Workers%205/
and
http://jsclipper.sourceforge.net/5.0.2.2/worker_main.html

Comment: You can create objects in the webWorker, do stuff to them there and then transfer ownership back to the main thread (or make a copy).  You cannot have any objects that both the main thread and the webWorker can have access to (for concurrency reasons) and you cannot modify any objects that are in the active DOM from a webWorker (also for concurrency reasons).  You don't disclose what your `main`, `head`, `torso`, etc... objects are so we can't comment on those.

Comment: Also, please don't think that more threads means perfectly concurrent operation.  Usually, it does not.  There are still only so many CPUs in a processor and only one DOM that can't be accessed simultenously by multiple threads.  I would think your best best would be CSS3 animations which would at least let browser native code do the animation and generally not be blocked by the single JS main thread.

Answer (score -1):

I have glanced by this post too many times without giving an answer. Figured someone might want it.

Use the function constructor `new Function(argIdentifiers...,scopeString)` as shown [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Function).

Comment: You might want to give a bit more detail, perhaps placing it in context.